# spaCy not picking up all ORG tags in sentence

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I am using spaCy to try and pick up ORG entity tags in sentences. However, it is not picking up all of the tags, and the ones that it does pick up vary depending on how the organization name is written. For example:

```py
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

doc = nlp("Apple, Microsoft, Google, and Facebook are all techo companies from the USA")
displacy.render(doc, style='ent')    # I am using `.render` as I am in a notebook
```

generates:
[image]
This is clearly missing out `Facebook`

while

```py
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

doc = nlp("Apple, Microsoft Inc, Google, and Facebook are all techo companies from the USA")
displacy.render(doc, style='ent')
```

generates:
[image]
now missing both `Google` and `Facebook`.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong, the models just aren't perfect. See [this issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3052) on Github, which explains that this is just part of how statistical models work.

Note that your examples seem to work as expected with the latest large English model for me.